# How can I prevent the initial "No records to display" message from appearing before the data is loaded into the react-data-table-component?

Tags: reactjs, mern, react-table, react-data-table-component

Below I am calling API and getting data from these ,but the issue is I open or reload the page 1st no records to display shows then the data loads why?for time taking to get data from api i am showing loader,loader is showing but after loader show "no records to display" shows,then data loads in data table.

```
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);            
const getRoles = async () => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        try {
            const apiRes = await ListRoles();
            if (apiRes.status === 200) {
                setLoading(true);
                setRoles(apiRes?.data?.data || []);
                const AlumniRole = apiRes?.data?.data.filter((item) => item?.role === "Alumni");

                if (AlumniRole) {
                    const roleId = AlumniRole[0].id;
                    setSelectedRoleId(roleId)
                }

            } else {
                setLoading(false);
                toast.error(apiRes?.data?.message || 'Something went wrong!, Please try again..!', {
                    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false);
            toast.error('Something went wrong!, Please try again..!', {
                position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
            })
        }
    }, 500);
};

const listAllAlumni = async () => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        try {
            const apiRes = await listAllUsers({ roleId: selectedRoleId });
            if (apiRes.status === 200) {
                setLoading(true);
                // const filteredData = apiRes?.data?.data?.filter(item => item?.id !== id).map(item => ({ ...item }));
                const filteredData = apiRes?.data?.data?.filter(item => item?.id !== id && item?.isPaymentCompleted !== false)
                    .map((item, index) => ({
                        id: item?.id,
                        slno: index + 1,
                        name: `${item?.firstName} ${item?.lastName}`,
                        firstName: item?.firstName,
                        lastName: item?.lastName,
                        email: item?.email,
                        mobileNo: item?.mobileNo,
                        passingOutClass: item?.passingOutClass || 'Not available',
                        avatar: item?.avatar,
                    }));
                // const searchedData = searchText
                //     ? filteredData.filter((row) => row.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
                //         .map((item, index) => ({ ...item, slno: index + 1 }))
                //     : filteredData;

                // setAlumni(searchedData || []);
                setAlumni(filteredData || []);
            } else {
                setLoading(false);
                toast.error(apiRes?.data?.message || 'Something went wrong!, Please try again..!', {
                    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false);
            toast.error('Something went wrong!, Please try again..!', {
                position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
            })
        }
    }, 500);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedRoleId) {
        listAllAlumni();
    }
}, [selectedRoleId])

useEffect(() => {
    getRoles();
}, [])
```

loader and dataTable,

```
{!loading ?<div>
                <Loader />
            </div> :
            <>

                <Card className='alumni_data'>
                    <DataTable
                        columns={columns}
                        data={alumni.filter((row) =>
                            row.name?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            row.passingOutClass?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
                        )}
                        defaultSortField="name"
                        sortIcon={<NorthIcon />}
                        pagination
                        paginationPerPage={50}
                        paginationRowsPerPageOptions={[50, 100, 500]}
                        selectableRows={false}
                        customStyles={tableCustomStyles}
                        fixedHeader
                        striped
                    />
                </Card>
            </>
        }
```

How can I fix this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about changing the condition from` {!loading ?` to `{(!loading && alumni.length === 0) ? }`

Comment: tried this,but still getting this same issue ,1st loader show then  "There are no records to display",then data loads.

Comment: use the loading condition inside the dame `<div>` instead of using different tags for `<Loader />` and  `<Card/>`